# How to argue that $\int_{0}^{t} |x(s) - y(s)|dt \leq \delta \max\limits_{s \in [0,1]} |x(s) - y(s)|$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, definite-integrals, proof-writing

$\int_{0}^{t} |x(s) - y(s)| dt \leq \delta \max\limits_{s \in [0,1]} |x(s) - y(s)|$

was in the last step (on pg 12, http://faculty.cord.edu/obihun/BanachTalk1.pdf) to prove uniqueness of ODE, where $x(t),y(t)$ are simple functions in $\mathbb{R}, \delta$ is a constant.

This inequality must have been obvious to me some while ago, can anyone remind me why this holds true?

Comment: Note that $t\in [0, \delta]$.

Comment: From what I can read in the slides, $t \leq \delta$. Are you asking why $\int_{[a,b]} |f(x)| dx \leq (b-a)\max_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)|$ in general?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter I am guessing the mean value theorem...wow that was a long time ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use the mean value theorem. Just use the following fact from riemann-integration:
If $$|f(x)| \leq |g(x)|$$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, then $$\int_{[a,b]} |f(x)| \leq \int_{[a,b]} |g(x)|.$$

Applying this to $$|x(s) - y(s)| \leq \max_{s \in [0,1]} |x(s)-y(s)| = M.$$  Notice that the max exists since $x,y$ are continuous and $[0,1]$ is compact. Since $M$ is constant, the integral of $M$ on $[0,t]$ is $$tM,$$ since $t \in [0,\delta]$, the integral is less than or equal to $$\delta M.$$